# Is it possible to have different z-index in the same div?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to have twice the same text, one above the other. This text is cut by an image.

These texts are in the same div that is centered, but their z-index remains the same.

I tried to change any z-index of my elements.

```css
.bottom {
  font-family: Gotham;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 144px;
  color: #ededed;
  position: absolute;
}

.up {
  font-family: Gotham;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 144px;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: #ededed 2px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  width: 465.125px;
  height: 144px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <p class="up">ZAIUS</p>
  <p class="bottom">ZAIUS</p>
</div>
```

I want to have the filled text under the image and the stroke text.
And the stroke text is supposed to be above the other one and the image.

Comment: yes, it is possible, provide z-index to '.bottom' also. be it 1

Comment: What do you mean by "This text is cut by an image"? And where will that image be shown in the DOM? In `div.group` or another element? And you want the image to be inbetween the filled text and the stroke text? What is the role of the filled text in such case? Is the image semi-transparent?

Comment: There is my issues on picture: https://imgur.com/a/k2nPpMk
Providing z-index to .bottom doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z-index` property is not required at all to achieve your goal, as you can see in the example below.

Furthermore the `z-index` should be omitted as long as possible to keep the code clean, reusable, maintainable and expandable.
Of course, in really small projects it is not as important as in larger ones.

```css
#frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.group {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  left: 10%;
  top: 30%;
}

.group img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
}

.big-letters {
  font-family: Gotham;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 144px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bottom {
  color: #ededed;
}

.up {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: #ededed 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="big-letters bottom">LOREM</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"/>
    <div class="big-letters up">LOREM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about z-index, but removing z-index from .up and changing position to relative works, if what i understand is correct.

```css
.bottom {
  font-family: Gotham;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 144px;
  color: #ededed;
  position: absolute;
}

.up {
  font-family: Gotham;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 144px;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: #ededed 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  width: 465.125px;
  height: 144px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <p class="up">ZAIUS</p>
  <p class="bottom">ZAIUS</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it doesn't work. The filled goes under the stroke one

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here, Just assign the stroked element a higher `z-index`. Also maybe you are getting confused due to the color of the text and the stroke being the same. I tried demonstrating it [HERE](https://www.useloom.com/share/9f370911660a48caaa612628d09391d1).

Comment: There is some screenshots of what I got and what I should get : https://imgur.com/a/k2nPpMk
If you want, I can try to create a codepen!

Comment: I had a look at your image, you should create a codepen.

Comment: Also from the snapshot, I see that the image is not a sibling of the text, did you try having the image as a sibling of both the element which you are trying to stack?

Comment: Specially since z-index tends to be grouped and restricted to the parent's or ancestors's z-index which ever is the first one eligible for a z-index.

Comment: There is the codepen: https://codepen.io/azogbiceps/pen/bZZLdb
It works but the image size is kinda hard to get back

Comment: Just tweaked the Image size and the position from left. https://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/vPPwmv